# Not able to install packages in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 (My PC is very Old and have low configuration 11.04 working well),but when i trying to install restricted extra codec,adobe flash getting error message "counld read from source"  i  software center.

Aslo when i am trying to install from command line it saying broken dependencies

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

When I executed the command apt-get -f install' i showing no packages to install 
0 Installed 0 upgraded.

How to resolve the this issue

Comment: See [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815) Once you set up your system to use the `old-releases` server, if the problem persists, see [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/22949) However, you should really upgrade to a supported release of Ubuntu (or some other OS). Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't even get security updates for newly discovered vulnerabilities, so it is actually dangerous to use. There are [official Ubuntu "flavors" that may run well on your old machine](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/22949).

Comment: If you are worried about the performance of your PC with Ubuntu 12.04 and later take a look at [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) both are supported here and will run on older hardware.

Comment: refer http://blaze-core.com/issuesresolutions-with-ubuntu-11-04/ it is explaining common issues with ubuntu 11.04 and its resoulution